# Implementing the same function for different objects

Tags: swift

Newbie coder and learning Swift. I want the function to be applicable for both UIButtons and couldn't figure out how to make it happen for second one.

```
private lazy var boostButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 80, height: 80)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "simsek.png"), for: .normal)
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    button.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDown), for: [.touchDown, .touchDragEnter])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUp), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchDragExit, .touchCancel])

    return button
}()

private lazy var informationButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 10, width: 35, height: 35)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yenigozlukgri.png"), for: .normal)
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    button.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDown), for: [.touchDown, .touchDragEnter])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUp), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchDragExit, .touchCancel])

    return button
}()
```

These are my buttons. I don't use storyboard but I believe that's not essential for the solution.

```
@objc func touchDown() {
    animator.stopAnimation(true)
    boostButton.backgroundColor = .red
    //highlightedColor
}

@objc func touchUp() {
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
        self.boostButton.backgroundColor = .gray
    })
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```

What I want to do is, when one of the buttons are clicked, it should perform the animation.  If I add *informationButton* like the *boostButton* to my functions, both of them perform the animation even though one button is clicked. It should work for just the clicked one. How can I fix it to be functional for even more buttons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parameter

```
 @objc func touchDown(_ sender:UIButton) {
    animator.stopAnimation(true)
    sender.backgroundColor = .red
    //highlightedColor
}

@objc func touchUp(_ sender:UIButton) {
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
         sender.backgroundColor = .gray
    })
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```